# Spring framework relationship mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mapping

My class Categorie needs to have multiple Products, i need to show the products when you click on a category in the jsp... I tried it like this:

```
@Entity
public class Categorie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int categorieId;
    private String categorieName;
    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "CategorieNr")
    private Set<Product> products;
```

My Product class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CentricProduct")
public class Product implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int productId;
    private int calories, productRow;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
    return false;
    }

    Product other = (Product) object;
    return description.equals(other.description);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return description.hashCode();
}
```

This is the repository i use to get the categorys with their products:

```
@Repository
public class CategoryRepository implements ICategoryRepository
{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public CategoryRepository() {
    }

    public CategoryRepository(EntityManager em) 
    {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager e)
    {
        this.em = e;
    }  

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<Categorie> findAll()
    {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Categorie.class));        
        return em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }
```

in my jsp:

```
  <h1 class="listtitle">Productenlijst</h1>
            <div id="leftlist" class="list" >     
               <c:forEach items="${products}" var="item" >                                   
               <form:form method="POST" action="shoppinglist.htm" modelAttribute="products">            
                 <input type="submit" value= "${item.categorieName}" class="productlistbtn" alt="Submit" input path="${item}" >   
               </form:form> 
                  </c:forEach>               
            </div>
```

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 0):

your class `Product` needs to be declared as `@Entity`. (you can't embed a one-to-many relationship, especially because you're `Product`contains it's own `ID`)

Comment: Ur right so i tried it like you said, i've changed my question above, would you be so kind to take a look at it? my products are still null...

Comment: i haven't written any unit tests, but if you want i could add the controller and repository code...

Comment: i added the code, if you want, i'll even want to mail you my project, it's for school anyway..

Comment: do you have test data in your datasource?

Comment: yeah and i linked them with the foreign key in the product table

Comment: now I used a DTO and i get the following error:
 failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: domain.Categorie.products, no session or session was closed